# "Access Denied" error appears in $ heroku logs --tail when I upload a picture in my APP to AWS with fog gem

Tags: heroku, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave, fog

unable to upload a picture file into S3 bucket in my APP with fog gem, even though I could upload locally.

I still can log into AWS successfully with correct IAM user name, who has AdministratorAccess and AmazonS3FullAccess policy names. I can see my S3 Bucket right there with a picture file which I have manually uploaded there before.

I tried with a different new user and I got "The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records." error message. I am trying 3rd new user while waiting for your answers.

In my carrier_wave.rb file,
    ...

```
if Rails.env.production?
CarrierWave.configure do |config|


config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
config.fog_credentials = {
  # Configuration for Amazon S3
  :provider              => 'AWS',
  :aws_access_key_id     => 'correct aws_access_key_id',
  :aws_secret_access_key => 'correct aws_secret_access_key',
  :region                => 'us-east-2',
  :host                  => 's3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
}
config.fog_directory     =  'correct bucket name'

 end
end
...
```

Any suggests would help me a lot since I have already run out of ideas. Thank you!

Comment: I had set this up successfully 2 or 3 years ago with a different APP of mine. But AWS has been changed a lot since. I have really lost this time. :-(

Comment: I added a 3rd user and used his credential and it magically worked this time, probably because I made the bucket's access "Objects can be public".